# Get all featured images from WordPress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I want to get featured images in mysql. Here is the query I have written but it says,

```
1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

Code:

```
SELECT p1.ID, p1.post_title, p1.post_excerpt, p2.meta_value, p1.guid, p4.guid
FROM wp_posts p1, wp_postmeta p3
    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta p2
        ON p1.ID = p2.post_id 
    AND p2.meta_key = '_price'
    AND p1.post_type = 'product'
    AND p1.post_status = 'publish'
    INNER JOIN wp_posts p4
        ON p4.ID = p3.post_id 
    AND p3.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
    AND p4.post_type = 'attachment'
```

Comment: After your edit, it no longer has a subquery. However, you need to remove , wp_postmeta p3 from the "FROM" clause and join it the same way you joined p2 and p4.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your query is that when you say

```
WHERE ID =
```

this means that it's equals to 1 value, but the sub query returns more than 1 value

There are 2 things you can do to fix it.

a. Change the sub query and narrow down the results to return 1 value

b. If it returns more than 1 value then change your query to

```
WHERE ID IN(----sub query----)
```